# Add custom datatype Odoo 8 or openerp 7

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I want to add a custom datatype and use it when declaring fields in odoo.
So I want it to be able to handle it like this: `my_field = fields.MyDataType`

What I've got so far can handle just that. But only when type is set to a type that already exists.

Why I want to implement this is because I want to be able to add a custom method to my field so I could call `my_field.mycustommethod()`

My code so far:

```
from openerp.fields import _String
from openerp.tools import ustr

from openerp import fields, models
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)



class MyDataType(_String):
    """ Very similar to :class:`~.Char` but used for longer contents, does not
    have a size and usually displayed as a multiline text box.

    :param translate: whether the value of this field can be translated
    """
    type = 'text'


    def convert_to_cache(self, value, record, validate=True):
        if value is None or value is False:
            return False
        return ustr(value)
```

Is this the way to go or am I thinking in the wrong direction?
And I probably have to declare a custom widget for this datatype?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right: declaring a new field type which inherits from an existing one.

As for example, check out [this](https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/one2many_sorted/)